# Change attribute after resize ? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui

I use [angular-ui carousel](https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel) ,and my directive now looks like this

```
<ui-carousel slides="value" 
             slides-to-show="calculateGamesCount"
             slides-to-scroll="calculateGamesCount"> 
      ... 
</ui-carousel>
```

Directive scope:

```
 show: '=slidesToShow',
 scroll: '=slidesToScroll',
```

From parent controller i get "calculateGamesCount" , but after window resize carousel directive attrs dont change, its stay the same.

```
$scope.calculateGamesCount = Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 90 ) / 232 );

// Get value after resize
angular.element($window).bind('resize',function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.calculateGamesCount = Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 90 ) / 232 ) ;
    });
});
```

How i can fix it ?

Comment: are you using bootstrap you can wrap into a col-xs-  and when resize it should resize too.

Comment: no , also carousel items witdh generates from carousel directive not from css

Comment: i mean you can put your <ui-corusel> inside a <div class="col-xs-12">, or if put some code to check it out and see explicity whats happen.

Comment: i was looking the documentation of angular-ui-carousel and is pending to implement responsive.  https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel#comming-soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's workaround for your condition. You can have following generic directive which watches change in window size. Then you can watch the `windowWidth` variable in your controller which set every time there's change in window width inside directive. Inside watch function you first delete the ui-carousel component on your view by using `ng-if` then assign newly calculated value of `calculateGamesCount` & then make ng-if to true. By doing this your directive will be re-rendered every time there's change in window width.

```
app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
            return {
                'h': w.height(),
                'w': w.width()
            };
        };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

        }, true);

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

Inside controller add this code:

```
$scope.$watch('windowWidth', function(n, o){
        $scope.showCarousel = false;
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.calculateGamesCount = Math.floor(( window.innerWidth - 90 ) / 232 );
            $scope.toShow = angular.copy($scope.calculateGamesCount);
            console.log($scope.calculateGamesCount);
            $scope.showCarousel = true;
        });
});
```

You can have `resize` directive on any parent element of `ui-carousel` tag directive.
Working plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ebi2b2z9o1IlbIMBcu8r?p=preview

Comment: Thanks , its look like good , everythink works perfect , but my controller can't watch 'windowWidth' value .

Comment: noo ,from here   console.log($scope.calculateGamesCount)   i see that it only works at once on start , and do nothink after resize

Comment: No it's working fine. Open that plunker preview in separate window then you'll have more than 2 value for calculateGamesCount. Just try resizing the window & for every resize you'll see the value on console.